# RDLC generate barcode using ZXing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, zxing

I am pretty new to the RDLC report feature, I am looking to generate labels from Product data within a SQL database. When the user opens this Product/Part they are greeted with the information. When the user then clicks a button this will open the Report which will pass the parameters across to the Report in order to generate the label.

[image]

```
        Dim myparam As ReportParameter
        Dim testParameter As New List(Of ReportParameter)

        myparam = New ReportParameter("PartID", "Test")
        testParameter.Add(myparam)

        myparam = New ReportParameter("MRPID", "Test MRP")
        testParameter.Add(myparam)

        myparam = New ReportParameter("PartName", "Test Name")
        testParameter.Add(myparam)

        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(testParameter)

        Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter
        writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
        PictureBox1.Image = writer.Write(MRPID)

        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

As you can see, I am using XLing to generate my barcodes, which I have been successful in making work with the 3 lines of code you see above. However, I have no idea how I can pass this or have this generate on the report when ran. The barcode will be generated from the MRPID ie(TV001232). I understand this part is wrong "writer.Write(MRPID)" but I replaced the parameter value with MRPID so you could understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm a little lost on what exactly the problem is.  What about this doesn't work?  Are you getting unexpected results, errors or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your image to Base64 string first using this:

```
Public Function ImageToBase64(ByVal image As Image, ByVal format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As String
    Dim base64String As String = ""
    Using ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        image.Save(ms, format)
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)
    End Using
    Return base64String
End Function
```

So this:

```
myparam = New ReportParameter("MRPID", "Test MRP")
testParameter.Add(myparam)
```

Should be like this:

```
Dim writer As New BarcodeWriter
writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128
myparam = New ReportParameter("MRPID", ImageToBase64(writer.Write(MRPID),<THE IMAGE FORMAT OF YOUR IMAGE>))
testParameter.Add(myparam)
```

Then, in your report set the following:

```
MIMEType = select the correct MIME type from the dropdown list
Source = Database
Value = <Expression>
```

and in the Expression window:

```
=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!MRPID.Value)
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution, thank you for taking the time to explain the steps I needed to take. I really appreciate your help. Would you happen to know if there is anyway to expand the ZXing libary to include all ASCII characters like underscore etc. At the moment if I can the underscore is replaced with a ? which isnt too much of an issue as I can replace this through code upon scan. I thought I would ask the question if it was at all possible

Comment: @Shadyjunior Sorry I'm not familiar with the ZXing library